# What is an efficient way to compare vectors (finding nearest vector) when saved separately?

Tags: python, processing-efficiency

Let's say I have a 11,523-dimension floating vector `s`, that is, whose shape is 1x11,523. (yes, not that compact.)

I also have 108,000 vectors to compare. Among these, I would like to have the closest vector to `s`. (In other words, I have 108,000 centroids in 11,523D, and I want to have the closest centeroid to `s`.)

Of course, 108,000x11,523 floating matrix is too large to save in one file. So each 36 centeroids are saved. (e.g., `c0000.pickle`, `c0001.pickle`, `c0002.pickle`, ..., `c2999,pickle`, each one is a 36x11,523 matrix).

I am just going through each file:

```
best_so_far = 1e10           # or, infinity
for file in files:
    centeroids = load(file)  # eg, `c0001.pickle`
    dist = distance_measure(s, centeroids)
    if dist < best_so_far:
        # update best
```

The process is quite slow now. Is there a better way to do this? Should I load several files up to a certain memory usage and calculate measure?

Comment: Along with complex calculation you are adding file I/O as well. This won't help I guess.

Comment: @Afaq so is your comment...

Comment: @YW if you need performance Python is the wrong tool. Maybe Matlab, Mathematica or any other tool that is not based on scripting language.

Comment: @alfasin I know , just giving out my thoughts. I would have used something like generators.

Comment: @Afaq generators won't improve performance (or at least not in a noticeable way).

Comment: If you are using a common distance measure like cosine then you can vectorise your operations.

Comment: Are you using `numpy` for this? Could you use a `scipy.sparse` matrix? What is your distance measure?

Comment: @alfasin using the `numpy`/`scipy` stack can often give you comparable performance to Matlab in this domain. Indeed, there is a highly performant implementation of just this operation in `sklearn`

Comment: You may take a look at this webpage:
https://iliauk.com/2016/02/16/millions-of-distances-high-performance-python/

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `there is a highly performant implementation of just this operation in sklearn–` which is?

Comment: @Chuck http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html